# Force edit record without modal dialog

Tags: lightning, salesforce1-app, component

I want to confirm from the gurus if it’s possible to display the object record in edit mode as an inline edit without the modal dialog popping?

I have a standard lightning page on a standard object with the related list and a bunch of other standard and custom lightning components. We will call this lightning page A.

I have a custom lightning component which is displayed quick action on one of the page layout. The responsibility of this quick action is to create a record on the background and redirect the user to the case record page in edit mode.

The way I do it is in the callback, once the ID is created, I used force:navigatetosobject component to send the user to the case detail record page and in my quick action, I am capturing the destroy event so that once the quick action modal dialog is destroyed, I can open the target record in edit mode so that all the associated related list, custom components on the case record page are loaded in the background. For this, I use force:editrecord.

Everything works great but the editrecord opens in a modal dialog. What I want is no modal but kinda like all the fields are displayed as an inline edit rather than modal display.

Is this possible?

Comment: did you ever find out if this was possible?

Comment: No man. I was not able to find a solution. I tried playing with the dom elements also but due to the locker service I was unable to achieve anything.